# Area of math dealing with sliding tiles?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, polyomino

I am not sure if this may be better suited for Computer Science, but I have recently gotten interested in problems having to do with different shapes of tiles sliding around in a grid. For example, what sets of tiles are able to be freely slid into all other configurations of those tiles? What shapes of tiles would be able to maneuver anywhere inside a given "arena"? Etc.

Has anyone studied this? If so, please point me to how I can learn more.

Comment: Sliding tiles? You may enjoy [this puzzle game](http://www.bricks-game.de/). It started out as an extension of Klocki, but then the designer invented various properties for the tiles (called bricks) and the floor, and how they interact... Brute forcing by computer is frowned upon though.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Interesting. I haven't seen that puzzle before, so thanks! I am a big Sokoban fan as well. I guess I was just thinking there are a lot of mathematical questions that can be asked about this sort of puzzle in addition to the computational questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you may search the [Mathematical Subject Classification](https://mathscinet.ams.org/msc/msc2010.html) database.

The [search for the keyword tiling in AMS Mathscinet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/msc/msc2020.html?t=&s=tiling&btn=Search&ls=s) gives a few hits.

```
05-XX           Combinatorics {For finite fields, see 11Txx}
05Bxx       Designs and configurations {For applications of design theory, see 94C30}
05B45   Combinatorial aspects of tessellation and tiling problems [See also 52C20, 52C22]
37-XX           Dynamical systems and ergodic theory [See also 26A18, 28Dxx, 34Cxx, 34Dxx, 35Bxx, 46Lxx, 58Jxx, 70-XX]
37Bxx       Topological dynamics
37B52   Tiling dynamics
52-XX           Convex and discrete geometry
52Cxx       Discrete geometry
52C20   Tilings in $2$ dimensions (aspects of discrete geometry) [See also 05B45, 51M20]
52C22   Tilings in $n$ dimensions (aspects of discrete geometry) [See also 05B45, 51M20]
52C23   Quasicrystals and aperiodic tilings in discrete geometry
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a very cool resource!

Comment: Usually the studies about tiling are about patterns, where sliding is not included. In other words, they allow the pieces to be lifted off the table and placed anywhere.